# Issue: Input type text need mouse action "focus" to be submitted

Tags: javascript

i want to change user name and password then submit form , i want do this by javascript console not by user behvaior , when i do this by javascript consol , the form submit old values . this my case i want submit form with new values that set by javascript console –

Comment: I don't understand your question. Let me try and give you some pointers: there is no "mouse focus", there is just focus -- an element can be focused or not focused. Indeed, HTML elements offer the [`focus` method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-focus). If your form submits with "old" values, then something else is wrong -- normally a form submits its actual values. Please post minimal example that shows your problem, with HTML and associated script(s).

Comment: There are many ways the value of a <input type="text"> can change, including:

copy/paste
modified with JavaScript
auto-completed by browser or a toolbar

I want my form submit new value if i changed the input values by JavaScript (getElementById) ,
current situation it not submit without mouse action in inputs , The Dom not listen the changes has been occured without mouse action

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. Forget about the myriad of ways the Web browser can rightfully change your form control values (autofill, being one). From experience, you will not be able to reliably detect all changes -- some of these happen _after_ your page is loaded and do *not* dispatch `change` event(s). Why do you need to prevent submission without mouse input? Just leave the accessibility to the user and their agent, please. Or I don't understand your problem.

Comment: i want to change user name and password then submit form , i want do this by javascript console not by user behvaior , when i do this by javascript consol , the form submit old values . this my case i want submit form with new values that set by javascript console

Comment: Please edit your question and incorporate the information you have given me in your comments so that it becomes clear in the question what it is that you want to do. That way it may benefit people coming here with similar problem(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to submit a form using your (developer) preferred values as opposed to ones filled out by user or their user agent (UA, aka the Web browser), for situations where the agent might "pre-fill" the form automatically at some point in time *after* the page is loaded (meaning you can't replace the values with your own as soon as the page is loaded by e.g. `onload` method / `"load"` event), your best bet, in my opinion, is to attach your own `onsubmit` implementation / event listener for the `"submit"` event:

```
function form_modify_values() {
    this.elements.username.value = "foo";
    this.elements.password.value = "bar";
}
```

```
form.onsubmit = form_modify_values;
form.requestSubmit(); /// Submit the form with `onsubmit` being called
```

If using event listeners (the form is not yours and/or one `onsubmit` is already defined which must not be "overriden"), instead of the `form.onsubmit = ...` statement above:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", ev => form_modify_values.call(ev.currentTarget));
```

Keep in mind the following:

- When the UA changes a form's values -- by "auto-filling" them, for example -- the document tree is not modified as no changes to any of element node's attributes or descendant node(s) are made, so using something like `MutationObserver` is not going to work.
- There is no specification mandating *at which point in time* a UA ought to "auto-fill" a form -- I know that some UAs change values *after* the page is loaded and `"load"` events are dispatched / `onload` is called, meaning you changing values in response is also not going to work as it's "too early".
- The `submit` method of a form element, does *not* dispatch the `"submit"` event, that's why its "evil twin" `requestSubmit` exists. Since you depend on doing things in the `"submit"` event handler / `onsubmit`, you must use `requestSubmit` method.

My advice to you is to instead think very hard about *why* you want to change values of a form for the user. Most users don't like their forms to be altered by anything else than their UA or themselves. There is also the `defaultValue` property, partially for this reason.

Comment: Thank you .. can i contact with you over any social media plateform ?

Comment: @ahmedelgendy I am sorry -- I can't commit to such support at this time. You can ask better questions and link me to these so that I can hopefully provide better answers, or just trust that other visitors of SO help you out. Harder problems have been solved here by mere questions and answers. I honestly wish you best of luck!